# Ferry to Lebanon?

Tags: turkey, ferries, cyprus, lebanon

[This company](http://www.akgunlerdenizcilik.com) used to offer ferry connections between Turkey and Lebanon. But, it's not possible to book a crossing with them.

Is there any company currently offering ferry crossings to Lebanon? From anywhere in the Mediterranean?

Comment: There's a [travel agency](https://ferries-turkey.com/ferry-routes/turkey-lebanon/tur-leb-ferry-en.html#start) which offers the route from Tasucu to Tripoli. I tried to figure out whether they use the company you linked to or some other but I couldn't find it on their webpage.

Comment: I found that one, too. But, their site is quite a mess and some of their information is provably wrong, meaning I didn't think it worth to pursue their offerings. In addition, these guys are indeed only agents. So, some company somewhere would have to offer the exact connection they do (if the connection exists).

Comment: This [Turkish travel agency](https://ferries-turkey.com/ferry-routes/turkey-lebanon/tur-leb-ferry-en.html#start) has more easily understood, and accessed, info on ferries, including those between Tasucu and Tripoli. It indicates that Aegean Ferry Services is a division of its agency (Aegean Tour Travel). It gives [good contact info, including emails and live chat](https://aegeantourtravel.com/general/aegean-en.html) when the office is open. You might have more success with it (I'm not affiliated; it was the result of a Google search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This agency](http://ferries-turkey.com) (also mentioned by @martin.koeberl and @giorgio) responded to my enquiry.

They are offering tickets for the ferry to Tripoli, from Tasucu, charging 200 USD for a one way. It leaves twice a week to Tripoli (but, they say, only once a week to Tasucu).